# Is there any case in which we can use 今日の間に?

Tags: grammar

I asked some Japanese and they said that 今日のうちに is practically useful but 今日の間に is impractical (never used).

Can anybody here give a confirmation about whether 今日の間に is really impractical or not? Please also give me some examples.

Comment: If you're talking about a [Plutonian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_period#Rotation_period_of_selected_objects) which comes to about six and half Earth days, I don't think it's impossible.

Comment: @broccoliforest: Could you give me some possible sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually do see and hear 「[今日]{きょう}の[間]{あいだ}に」 once in a while, if not very often.  It may not be as common or even "proper" as 「[今日中]{きょうじゅう}に」, but it would be utterly incorrect to say that it is "never used" as your friends seem to have stated.

In fact, I just happened to find out that 「今日の間に」 is used as the first definition of 「今日中」 [in this online dictionary](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BB%8A%E6%97%A5%E4%B8%AD).

It is not a phrase that I recommend that Japanese-learners use actively, but it sure exists and it is a fact.

Answer (score 3):

I think 今日の間に is rarely used but 今日中に is in common use.

Answer (score 3):

今日の間に(内に) sounds awkward to me. We say 今日中に in the same way as 明日中に、今月中に、昨年中に, and don’t say 明日の間に、今月の間に、and rarely say 昨年(一昨年) の間に.

To me, “… のうちに” looks close to ‘in’ and ‘within’ in English, and “の間に” more alike “during.”

We say ”今日中に仕事を片付ける - We will finish the work (within) today / by the end of day," and rarely say ”今日の間に仕事を片付ける - We will finish the work during today.

Comment: Is the reading of 中 here ”じゅう" or "うち"?

Comment: 中  here readsじゅう. To "うち," "内" is applied to as a kanji description.